# how do i map a finite-many down to 1 with a priority

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

My input document has a finite number of possible values.  Those values need to be read as an aggregate and the highest existing priority reported as a single value.  So for instance:

if my possible input tags were: (but not all of them are always present and an order is not garunteed)

```
<SomeInput>A</SomeInput>
<SomeInput>B</SomeInput>
<SomeInput>C</SomeInput>
<SomeInput>D</SomeInput>
```

and my priority was A, then B, then C, then D.   In this case I would want my output to be:

```
<SomeOutput>A</SomeOutput>
```

in the case of:

```
<SomeInput>D</SomeInput>
<SomeInput>B</SomeInput>
```

should yield:

```
<SomeOutput>B</SomeOutput>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*[. eq min(/*/*/string())][1]
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[. eq min(/*/*/string())][1]" priority="2">
     <someOutput><xsl:apply-templates/></someOutput>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*/*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment, wrapped into a single top element to make it a wellformed XML document):

```
<t>
    <SomeInput>A</SomeInput>
    <SomeInput>B</SomeInput>
    <SomeInput>C</SomeInput>
    <SomeInput>D</SomeInput>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<SomeOutput>A</SomeOutput>
```

**When the same transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<t>
    <SomeInput>D</SomeInput>
    <SomeInput>B</SomeInput>
</t>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<SomeOutput>B</SomeOutput>
```